# How to write dax table filter to get the effect of OR criteria or an UNION criteria?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I had 3 tables: dimUser, dimProduct, factSales. Both dims filter the Sales table based on userid and productid.

I have applied RLS to dimUser based on email. Thus only the relevant record from dimUser gets filtered and automatically the corresponding factSales records get filtered.

However, user can see all records from dimProduct so I have added RLS to the dim table as follows:

```
[DW_PRODUCTID] IN SELECTCOLUMNS(FILTER(factSales,RELATED(dimUser[User_Email])=
USERPRINCIPALNAME()), 
"DW_ProductID", factSales[DW_ProductID])
```

Now only the relevant Products are shown.

All good so far.

Now I have another fact table called factPurchases. This table also has userid, productid. So I want to update the above RLS on product table so that I include even those products that are in the product table.

I believe that the solution is to either:

1. Union:

   [DW_PRODUCTID] IN **UNION(**
   SELECTCOLUMNS(FILTER(factSales,RELATED(dimUser[User_Email])=USERPRINCIPALNAME()), "DW_ProductID", factSales[DW_ProductID])
   **,**
   SELECTCOLUMNS(FILTER(factSales,RELATED(dimUser[User_Email])=USERPRINCIPALNAME()), "DW_ProductID", factPurchases[DW_ProductID])
   **)**
2. OR:

   **OR(**
   [DW_PRODUCTID] IN SELECTCOLUMNS(FILTER(factSales,RELATED(dimUser[User_Email])=USERPRINCIPALNAME()), "DW_ProductID", factSales[DW_ProductID])
   **,**
   [DW_PRODUCTID] IN SELECTCOLUMNS(FILTER(factPurchases,RELATED(dimUser[User_Email])=USERPRINCIPALNAME()), "DW_ProductID", factPurchases[DW_ProductID])
   **)**

I'm not sure which option is appropriate and syntax. Any help is appreciated please.

Comment: The Union expression is correct, is it not working for you?